# What is wrong with my beginner Brainfuck addition program?

Tags: addition, brainfuck

I've been working on this programming challenge: http://www.codeabbey.com/index/task_view/summing-up

Which basically states:

```
Input data has two values A and B in the single line.
Output should have the sum A+B printed into it.
Additionally after the stop the program should have values A, B, A+B in the cells 0, 1 and 2 respectively.
```

So for example input would look like this:

```
9 26
```

Now, I think I be misunderstanding either the problem or the solution because I believe the solution is supposed to be `9 26 35` where 9, 26, and 35 are all in their own cells.

My solution returns `9 26 35` and I believe in the correct cells (0,1, and 2 respectfully) but I am getting the answer wrong. Can anyone please look at the problem and my code and tell me where I am going wrong?

Code:

```
;:>;:><[-<+>]<:
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried plugging this into a couple of online brainfuck interpreters.  There is one here:

http://copy.sh/brainfuck/

and another here:

http://esoteric.sange.fi/brainfuck/impl/interp/i.html

In both cases, I needed to change your character set slightly --> : becomes . and ; becomes ,

The output from both was

```
    9 Y
```

Notice that 35 - 9 = 24, and Y is the 24th letter of the alphabet.  I think you are outputting the number "35" and having it interpretted as a letter.

I would try changing the program so that your output is literally single digits of the answer -- ie, output a 3, then output a 5, instead of outputting a numerical "35" (but leave the numerical value in cell 2 at the end).  In other words, your text output should be a formatted version of the values in memory, rather than just outputting the numerical values directly.

Comment: I noticed other interpreters ran code differently than CodeAbbey, but I'm trying to solve it on CodeAbbey so I kept it the way it was seeing as it worked there well enough it seems. Besides that though, thank you for the suggestion, I'll change it up and see if I can get it to work.

Comment: I initially looked up the character set on Wikipedia, that's where I got the idea to sub in ',' and '.'  It appears to just be two different dialects (I like CodeAbbeys personally -- seems a lot easier to read).

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the output should only have `A+B` printed, not `A`, `B`, and `A+B`, as you're doing with `:`.

And your result seems like it'll have `A+B` in cell 0, and 0 in cell 1 (essentially the same as the example code).

`><` is just cancelling itself out.